# JQuery wysiwyg editor plugin with options to add form elements

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jQuery wysiwyg editor plugin which has options to add HTML/HTML5 elements like buttons, textbox, radio buttons etc. I found very good wysiwyg editor: CKEditor, but it's just HTML editor. It doesn't allow to add button's/textboxes or other form elements. Can anyone please suggest me a good jQuery based HTML editor which allow to add form elements also?

Thanks in advance

Comment: CKEditor does have form elements: http://ckeditor.com/demo#full

Comment: Thanks Chris. I didn't notice it earlier